# owner-draw tab control - No HOTTRACK anymore

Tags: winapi, tabs, ownerdrawn

The tab control is created with TCS_HOTTRACK attribute, so when the mouse is over a non-selected tab item, this item will be highlighted (with blue color in Windows 7).

Now, I am trying to do owner-draw tab control. But when the mouse is over a non-selected tab item, the parent control of this tab control doesn't receive WM_DRAWITEM message. So I lost the feature of
hot track if I want to do owner-draw for tab control.

Is there any (good) way to do owner-draw for tab control with hot track feature?

Comment: Unsurprising, owner draw for the tab control is in general pretty lossy.  It doesn't work in winforms either, for example.  Subclassing and using WM_MOUSEMOVE, calling Invalidate() when you see another tab being hovered would be a workaround of sorts.

Comment: @HansPassant: I tried what you said. Now the parent get WM_DRAWITEM message when the mouse is over a non-selected tab item, but lpDis->itemState is always 0, so it is of no use. Of course I can do one more test (if the mouse is over a non-selected item) inside the (my own) drawing function `PanelOnDrawItem`, but do you know if there is a better way?